# How can I iterate a for loop in Python in the increments of sum of another variable and iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, increment

I am trying to make a python program for "The Sieve Of Eratosthenes"
but I am stuck at one place.

The c program I wrote looks something like this :

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (prime[i] == 0)
    {
         for (j = i*i; j <= n; j += i)
         {
             prime[j] = 1;
         }
    }
}
```

How will I write the code for `for(j=i*i;j<=n;j+=i)` in Python?

As by default python increment the iterator by `1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

```py
# rest of the code
# . 
# .
  j = i*i
  while j <=n:
    # resut of the code
    j += i
```

Answer (score 0):

You code could be rewritten like this

```
for i  in range(2,n+1, 1):
  if prime[i]==0:
    for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
      prime[j]=1
```

The range function takes upto 3 values, the first is the starting value, the second is the ending value (exclusive)  and the third is the amount to step each time.

The full semantics of `range` can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Im a little confused because I have no idea what the syntax of C is, but I assume you want to do something along the lines of

```
for i in range(n): # run from 0 to the value of n (int)
    if prime[i] == 0: # assuming prime is a list
        for j in range(i**2): # runs from 0 to the value of i squared
            prime[j] = 1
```

This code should work in terms of syntax and actually running (assuming you have defined prime and n somewhere), but you may have to do some tweaking to the for loops to make it acheive the desired effect. Remember, a for loop in that way of construction will have a temporary variable called i that is 0, and as long as the value of i is less than the value of n, the code will run and each time i will increment itself by one. If you want to change it a bit, you could use range(start, stop, step), in which the start is the starting value of i (not 0), and stop is the stopping value (n). step is also the amount in which the variable of i will increment itself by each time the code loops.

I hope this helps. please ask any questions you have.